# Why ker(1) is a semi M-ideal in $\ell_1$?

Tags: banach-spaces

A subspace $Y$ of $X$ is said to be semi M-ideal if $\exists$ a projection $P$ (not necessarily linear) from $X^*$ to $Y^\perp$ such that $\|x^*\|=\|Px^*\|+\|x^*-Px^*\|$. And also, $P(\lambda x^*+Py^*)=\lambda Px^*+Py^*$ , $\forall x^*, y^*\in X^*$.

It is known that $ker(\mathbb{1})$ as a subspace of $\ell_1$ is a semi M-ideal, where $\mathbb{1}\in \ell_\infty$. My question is what is the corresponding projection $P:\ell_\infty\to sp\{\mathbb{1}\}$ which satisfies above norm decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a=(a_n) \in \ell_\infty$ let $m(a) = (\sup a_n + \inf a_n)/2$. Then $a\mapsto P(a)=m(a) 1$ is the projection you're looking for.

Dirk

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow Dirk!

Comment: That's for real valued $\ell_\infty$. Will you replace it with the circumecenter of the sets of values in complex case? I haven't check...

Comment: @Uri  The complex case is much harder, see E. Behrends's paper in Math. Ann. 290, No. 3, 463-471 (1991).